# Disable automatic parenthesis insertion in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, autocomplete, parentheses

I'm struggling with making Visual Studio (C++) stop automatically inserting closing parentheses and brackets. With curly braces I could disable it. (with turning the setting "Automatic brace completion" off)

I deactivated IntelliSense to make sure that it and its settings are not the culprit and deactivated all settings that I thought could be related to this problem, but without success.

**Example**:
when I write code it automatically results in this:

```
functionName(parameter));
```

since the closing parenthesis also doesn't get replaced by my typed parenthesis I end up with syntactically incorrect code that I have to manually fix by deleting one of the parentheses - which is very annoying.

Is there a possibilty to deactivate this "Feature" or activate the replacement of the closing parenthesis, which is common in other IDEs like IntelliJ and Eclipse?
Are there hidden settings that give more control over this kind of things?

Used Version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uncheck the "Automatic brace completion" option. Go to menu Tools > Options, then 
choose Text Editor > C/C++ > General.

[image]

When you type `{ ( [ " ' /*` it will not put the chars `} ) ] " ' */`

Comment: I already unchecked this option, but it only disables the automatic completion of braces, so when I type { it doesn't close it, but all the others still do close automatically. Are you sure that for you it works? Which Visual Studio version are you using?

Comment: For folks with ReSharper installed: ReSharper has an option that can overwrite this so just disabling this is not enough. Go to the ReSharper settings [Environment/Editor/Behavior/Braces and Parentheses] and uncheck "Auto-insert pair brackets, parentheses and quotes". The VS option from this answer might also need to be unchecked.
Edit: braces {} still get closed automatically but the rest works. Have to investigate further if this is a bug or another setting.

Answer (score 1):

After starting Visual Studio in [SafeMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278(v=VS.80).aspx) the insertion problem went away, and the "Automatic brace completion" option behaved as sergiol described, pointing towards an external extension beeing the cause of the problem.
And indeed, after deactivating the [EclipseKeymap extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alphabotsec.vscode-eclipse-keybindings), which I didn't remember having had installed, the problem was resolved.
Also, even with the automatic brace completion activated when I type the closing parenthesis it now gets replaced, as I am used to from other IDEs..